# Is there any way to get the file where a class was instantiated in auto-loading features in PHP?

Tags: php, autoload, spl-autoloader

Its similar question of [Is there an easy way to get the file where a class was instantiated in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739730/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-the-file-where-a-class-was-instantiated-in-php) but with different approach.

I need to know the source in autoloading (__autoload() or spl_autoload()) functions so that  I can load right class of sub-namespacing

Lets illustrate my problem a little bit by an example -
Please consider my following classes:
/my/project/root/faculties/faculty.class.php [namespace: faculties]
/my/project/root/faculties/faculty1/faculty.class.php [namespace: faculties/faculty1]
/my/project/root/faculties/completely/different/project/at/deep/project/root/faculties/faculty.class.php [namespace: faculties]

Now if I want to access instance of that different project its conflict with root project cause its same namespace.

Comment: Have you looked at the [PSR 4 FIG definition](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) and it's corresponding [example implementation](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/examples/)

Comment: As far as I know, it'd would have to be through `debug_backtrace()`. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/190421/caller-function-in-php-5

Comment: @delikan: yes, its an alternative. i don't think this way, thanks